# How to share a wireless Internet connection as a wireless hotspot?

Tags: networking, internet

Without going into details, the machine I use connects to a wireless network to get Internet access. Other devices aren't allowed on this network. Also, I do not have administrator access.

I can already run a wireless hotspot using NetworkManager, and switch to my Internet connection and back, but I can't do the two at the same time.

I want to create a wireless hotspot simultaneously with my wireless Internet connection (single adapter). I'm pretty sure this is possible, since I have a Qualcomm/Atheros card.

I'm very familiar with Linux commands so I have no problem getting directions involving use of `iptables`, `route`, etc.

Comment: I am far from an expert on this subject, but I would think you'd need to wireless NICs to do that

Answer (score 1):

Iptables and manual routing aren't necessary when using Ubuntu's provided defaults.

You would need **two Network Interface Adapters** to provide a Hotspot via Ubuntu.

### NIC #1

This will be used for your connection to the internet.  While both NICs could be wireless, this NIC (**the connection NIC**) is usually a wired NIC.  For your particular case, I used a wireless NIC for testing these steps.

### NIC#2

The second NIC (in the case of your question details, a Wireless adapter) will be used for configuring as a Hotspot to share the connection (**the Hotspot NIC**).

Configuring one NIC won't affect the other.

You can setup your Ubuntu Hotspot connection using three parts:

- **Part 1: Create the Hotspot network**
- **Part 2: Edit/Configure the Hotspot network**
- **Part 3: Start the Hotspot service**

### Create the Hotspot Network

```
-> (From the System Settings menu (click) Network)
-> (Select the desired Wireless Device) -> (click) Use as Hotspot
-> (The Hotspot is Network is created) -> (Click the ON/OFF button to turn it off)
-> (Exit the Network Window)
```

### Edit/Configure the new Hotspot network

```
-> (From the Connection Icon of the Ubuntu Top Panel click) Edit Connection
-> (Select the new Hotspot connection that has been created) -> (click) Edit
-> (fillin Connection name) My Hotspot (the name can be any name including spaces
-> (fillin SSID) My Hotspot (This is what appears in the hotspot connections)
-> (Mode: select) Hotspot
-> (Device: select the NIC #2... not the already NIC connected to the Internet)
-> (The other items can be left at default) -> (click the tab) WiFi Security
-> (From the drop-down slect and fillin the preferred access code type)
-> (click) Save -> (click) Save
```

*(**Important:**
 To make changes to the Hotspot configuration, the Hotspot has to be turned off first in Part 1*)

### Activate the Hotspot

```
-> (Go back to the Network icon in the top panel)
-> (click) Create New Wi-Fi Network
-> (Wi-Fi Adapter: Select the desired Wi-Fi adapter (the NIC #2)
-> (Connection: Select the Network Name you configured in part 2 above.
-> (click) Create
```

Your new network will now show availability in the list of wireless networks.  These connections are handled by your Hotspot and are invisible to your original provider.  I tested the steps on an internet Hotspot that has a web interface for the computer connection.  The Ubuntu Hotspot provides access without having to connect to the Web interface.

To turn off your Ubuntu Hotspot perform **Part 1**... click the ON/OFF button to **OFF**

Comment: is there a "Use as Hotspot" option? Never seen it.

Comment: You're find it in the `Part 1` of the steps in the answer.  The option is there.  The option to turn it on or off is there.  The wording of the option (as indicated in the answer) is **Use as Hotspot**.  Which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm using Xubuntu 16.04. I'm aware that the option is there, I've just never seen it in one, easy to use button.

Comment: Can you see the button now?  I don't use Xubuntu.  I thoroughly tested  to provide easy steps for using Two Wireless NIC's instead of Wired and Wireless, which is more common.  Hopefully, you'll test the it and give back to the **AU** community by upvode and possibly accepting the answer if it works.  This will make it easier for others looking for similar help to find workable resolutions that have merit.  If you're having problems with bringing it up on XUbuntu, I'll take the time to install and test it on that.  On Ubuntu 16.04 while there are a number of steps, the operation is seamless.

Comment: I'll check today and get back to you.

Comment: You said you need 2 network adapters to do this. However, couldn't you do this with a wireless adapter that has multiple radios? (ex. 2x2:2) I believe the technology is called MU MIMO.